# " ' " single quote sign in Cypress

Tags: html, typescript, cypress

I want to write a test like:

```
cy.get('table').contains('th', 'Reviewer&#39;s comment').should('exist');
```

in the application I have a column called 'Reviewer's comment' but in the `contains` I am not able to use single quote sign, I was trying with the code `&#39;` but does not work:

[image]

Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you tagged [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript), I'm assuming that code is TypeScript. In TypeScript (and in JavaScript too), you can escape `'` using `\'`, but you don't need to escape if you use `"` to delimit the sting. Try this:

```
cy.get('table').contains('th', "Reviewer's comment").should('exist');
```

Comment: Solved, thanks, in a 9minutes will sign as resolved.